# How could I resolve unresolved UserProfileService?

Tags: spring-security

I have `UserProfileService` field declare in a class that implement `AuthenticationProvider` as shown below:

```
public class AdAuthenticationController implements AuthenticationProvider {

   private UserProfileService userProfileService;
}
```

Somehow there is an error mention `UserProfileService cannot be resolved to a type`. I'm using Spring Security version 3.1.3, any clue on this error?

Comment: Is it in classpath? Have you imported it?

Comment: @holmis83 yes. it is.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the missing Spring annotation @Autowired which inject this service into the Controller. Try this :

```
public class AdAuthenticationController implements AuthenticationProvider {

   @Autowired
   private UserProfileService userProfileService;
}
```